# Eliminate smoke smell from BBQ out of clothing

Tags: cleaning, clothing, smell, laundry

I was at a BBQ and because of some stronger wind, there was a lot of smoke from the fire so now my clothing is smelling after it.

Are there any quick solutions to get the smell of smoke out of clothes if you don't have time to put it into the clothes washer?

Answer (score 3):

I do a lot of grilling for friends who don't appreciate the smell of a fine grill smoke. I have a bottle of Febreze Heavy Duty fabric refresher that I spray my clothes down with post-grilling. It seems to get the smell down to a level that doesn't bother others.

I also keep an extra set of clothes with me in the car if I BBQ away from home. It's good practice anyway, imho.

Comment: I also tried it with that and after a good spraying and hanging the clothes outside for a while, it was pretty good. Therefore +1, but I wait another time until I will accept an answer, because I would prefer a solution with more common requirements. One does not always have a bottle of Febreeze in the house...

Comment: @ByteCommander you might try spraying with just water to see if there's really anything active in febreze or if somehow the moisture is doing all the work. Although this site tends to eschew product recommendations and encourages out-of-the-box solutions, you can accept this answer now and then change that choice at any time if a new answer is posted.

Comment: @briantist Yes, of course I can accept it and later accept another answer instead. It's just that answered and accepted questions don't attract that much new answers as one that is not accepted yet...

Comment: @ByteCommander true, just mentioning it as some people don't realize.